# Sorting data using EF DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

Is there a way to pass an order by clause to a DbSet class in EF?

I'm using C#

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am not sure how to do that from *DbSet*, but you can do this from *DBContext* by getting access to the *IQueryable*

```
private readonly DbContext context;
...
context.Set<T>().OrderBy(item => item.Property)
```

Comment: I know this is not exactly what I asked, but it does the job right there in the view

Answer (score 4):

What about using `.OrderBy` directly on the Entity?

```
db.Employees.OrderBy(p => p.Id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here db.Employees is a DBSet. Is that what you're trying to do?

```
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public DBContext db;
        public void MyMethod
        {
            foreach (var emp in db
                .Employees
                .Where(e => e.IsActive) // (or whatever)
                .OrderBy(e => e.LastName))
            {
                DoSomething(emp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Alexandre you can do that in query like:

```
var emps = from e in _db.Employees
            orderby e.FirstName
            select e;
```

Here _db.Employees is DbSet.

Answer (score 1):

this would have to be done in a query,

or you would need to define a QueryView in the Edmx.

a QueryView can be used to specify / order / filter the data.

Have a look at this : [DefiningQuery versus QueryView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2008/12/19/definingquery-versus-queryview.aspx)

Comment: you can consume an EDMX from code first, but then again it kinda defies the whole code first concept.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

var items = DataContext.Employees.OrderBy(x=> x.Name).ToList();
```

Or, for async:

```
var items = await DataContext.Employees.OrderBy(x=> x.Name).ToListAsync();
```